# Error using \ref in captions with Tufte and Babel

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, babel, tufte

I am using the tufte-book class. 
When referencing with \ref within a caption using the babel package I get two errors:

"Argument of \@iiminipage has an extra }." and
"Paragraph ended before \@iiminipage was complete."

The error does not occur when using \autoref instead of \ref or when deactivating babel.

Code example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,justified,symmetric,notoc]{tufte-book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics{fig1}
\caption{xxx}
\label{fig:one}
\end{marginfigure}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\includegraphics{fig2}
\caption{Figure \ref{fig:one}...}
\label{fig:two}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm investigating, but if you don't use shorthands in `\ref` you can use the package option `safe=bib` or `safe=none`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to lie in the redefinition of `\ifthenelse` made by `babel` and interaction with `tufte-common.def` that (wrongly) loads `hyperref` before other user packages.

Apparently, using `\protect\ref` in the argument to `\caption` (although theoretically it shouldn't be necessary) fixes the issue.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics{fig2}
\caption{Figure \protect\ref{fig:one}...}
\label{fig:two}
\end{figure}
```